# Loop that works in debug but not release

Tags: while-loop, crash, release, swift4.2, xcode10.1

I updated my xcode 9.4 to 10.1 and swift 3.3 to 4.2. I have the following code in my app, which iterates over a while loop and waits till flag (**isReceivedAdTagResponse**) becomes true.

`while self.isReceivedAdTagResponse == false
{
    continue
}`

This code works fine in debug mode, but crashes in release mode. Strange is that the same code works in release mode too if I just add print statement.

`while self.isReceivedAdTagResponse == false
{
     print("hi")
     continue
}`

Somewhere I found the solution to change the **"Optimization Level"** build setting to **None [-O0]** and it works.

I want to release the app to the store. Will my app crash if I will keep run mode as debug mode and archive the release build?

Or do I must have to change the **"Optimization Level"** build setting to **None [-O0]** before releasing it. Is it a good practice?

I am little confused. Please guide.

Comment: It has nothing related to debug or release build. It is a very bad idea to "wait" in the loop, even though the .isReceived AndTagResponse is thread-safe. DON'T USE IT!!! NEVER!!!

Comment: I really understand but I am willing to modify it in next release please. Because code is already written and I have to make a release build urgently. please help with the solution.